# Virtual Box does not use GPU on Surface Book 2

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, gpu

I have a Surface Book 2 that has a GTX 1060. In case you don't know, Surface Book 2 can switch between the integrated GPU and the dedicated GPU seamlessly. This works great for Photoshop as evident in the Task Manager; a slight bump in the usage of the dGPU.

However, this doesn't seem to occur when using Virtual Box. While running Hackintosh, I do not see a bump in the usage of the dGPU. Instead, the integrated GPU is being used.

I already have done the NVidia Control Panel setting that sets which GPU gets priority on certain applications. That doesn't seem to affect anything.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? What is there to do?

Here is a screenshot of my Virtual Box settings.

[image: Virtual Box Settings]

Comment: Disable the iGPU in the BIOS so that Windows has no choice in the matter.

Comment: In order for VirtualBox to use your dGPU your CPU has to support VT-d is that the case?  MacOS running on non-Apple hardware is not supported.  So you really shouldn't expect the VM in question to actually work.  In order to clarify what is going on VirtualBox itself will never use a GPU, it has no need for one, the entire point is for the guest OS to use it instead of the host OS anyways.  This is done through hardware virtualization, specifically, vt-d in a case like this.

Comment: @Ramhound Hmm... I see. So basically, I really shouldn't be expecting components to work smoothly due to the nature of the mismatched hardware. This unfortunately includes the GPU not being able to communicate with Virtual Box properly. Okay. Thanks Ram. I appreciate your response.

Comment: In order for the GPU to communicate with the guest OS, the CPU must support VT-d, VT-x while similar (and still required) does allow for that.